# Python multidimensional dict and list together with ordered index

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a multidimensional dict and list in Python where the first entry is unique (dict), and within that entry, there can be multiple entries (list).

For example (dict with a list):
`{'0001': ['Value 1 for id 0001', 'Value 2 for id 0001', 'Value 3 for id 0001']}`

This would work, how ever I would like to be able to access my dict/list with something like this: `myList[0][1]` and I would like it to return `'Value 2 for id 0001'`
I'm not really sure where to go from here and I'm starting to think that I've gotten all this the wrong way around since I'm using a `dict` to be able to create a unique first entry and a second entry `list` with multiple values.

```
queue = {}

def add_to_dict(dict, key, values):
    """Append multiple values to a key in dict"""
    if key not in dict:
        dict[key] = list()
    dict[key].extend(values)
    return dict

add_to_dict(queue, '0001', ['Value 1 for id 0001'])
add_to_dict(queue, '0001', ['Value 2 for id 0001'])
add_to_dict(queue, '0001', ['Value 3 for id 0001'])

res = {key: queue[key] for key in queue.keys() & {'0001'}}
print(res)
```

Output:
`{'0001': ['Value 1 for id 0001', 'Value 2 for id 0001', 'Value 3 for id 0001']}`

How can I go from here to be able to access `0001` and `index 1`?

```
print(queue[0][1]) # I want this to return "Value 2 for id 0001"
```

The above will not work but thats the part I would like to get working.

The first [] has to be unique, but should be able to hold multiple values within that second list.

Let me know in the comments if I'm missing something and I'll update the question.

Comment: `list(queue.values())[0][1]`?

Comment: @anon01 well...to be really fast - use C++, with perfect optimization and direct memory access - c++ has you covered

Comment: @anon01 author not really clarified what he want, the rest is just speculations

Comment: @Nick your comment actually solved it all. Thank you!

Comment: "This would work, how ever I would like to be able to access my dict/list with something like this: `myList[0][1]` and I would like it to return `'Value 2 for id 0001'`"
Never said anything about performance ^^

Comment: @Persson cool - I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

use list instead of dict...

```
queue = [['Value %d for id %04d'%(n+1,i+1) for n in range(3)] for i in range(1)]
print(queue[0][1])

'Value 2 for id 0001'
```

You can use dict but seems overkill:

```
queueDict = {i+1:['Value %d for id %04d'%(n+1,i+1) for n in range(3)] for i in range(1)}
print(queue[0][1])

'Value 2 for id 0001'
```